# Attempt to compare number < Instance but it's the value, not the instance (i checked and tried)

Tags: lua, roblox

So I am making a Roblox game and everything went well, i fixed all the issues except this one, I can't figure out why it doesn't work and still says "attempt to compare number < Instance" because I need a remote event from the client's side to fix the capacity of the backpack (I need to put the default value at 10 but it is 0 because it is just for rising events and being sure that it doesn't cause more code in the same script and be lost).

I checked the client's side if I used a number value or just number: only 10 - I checked the parameters of the remote event on the server's side script: number - I checked if I used a variable at the beginning of the script, I changed the parameter's name: still error... I checked Roblox's devforum, nothing (*don't ask me why I don't use devforum*)

## **Code**:

**Server sided script**

```lua
remoteEvents:FindFirstChild("FixBackpackCapacity").OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, maxCapacityFC : number)

   if maxCapacityFC ~= nil and maxCapacityFC > 0 then
      player:FindFirstChild(player.EquippedBackpack.Value):FindFirstChild("MaxCapacity").Value = maxCapacityFC
    
   end

end)
```

**Client sided script**

```lua
game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").RemoteEvents.FixBackpackCapacity:FireServer(player, 10)
```

## Notes

1. I tried to remove `maxCapacityFC ~= nil`, it is still triggering the same error
2. It is at the right place, the condition is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fire a RemoteEvent from the client, the `player` object is supplied by the engine to the server. For example, if the client passes `a, b, c`, the server will receive `player, a, b, c`.

In your case, the client is providing `player, 10`, so the server is receiving `player, player, 10`. That is why `maxCapacityFC` is acting like an Instance, because it has been assigned as an Instance of a Player.

To fix your issue, simply remove the `player` variable from the `FireServer` call.

```lua
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local FixBackpackCapacity = ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvents.FixBackpackCapacity

FixBackpackCapacity:FireServer(10)
```

Comment: I'm gonna try this right now, thank you, I tought of that but I gave up this tought, make me even more stupid after realizing that I was correct but gave up the idea. Thanks. I think I should think twice before posting here.